# Algorithm to reduce a software version?

Tags: python, algorithm

I've been struggling with this problem in the last few hours and couldn't figure out a solution by myself. The problem is simple:

```
In: 'subtract('1.1.5', 4)'
Out: '1.1.1'

In: 'subtract('1.1.5', 6)'
Out: '1.0.9'

In: 'subtract('1.0.0', 1)'
Out: '0.9.9'

In: 'subtract('1.14.5', 8)'
Out: '1.13.7'

In: 'subtract('1.10.10', 20)'
Out: '1.9.0'
```

I've come up with a couple of really complex algorithms for a complex that seems so simple to solve, any ideas?

This is what I've tried so far (not working for all cases):

```
def subtract(version, sub):
  arrV = version.split('.')
  index = len(arrV) - 1
  sub = -abs(sub)

  while(sub < 0 and index >= 0):

    vLen = len(arrV[index])
    m = 10 ** (vLen - 1)
    i = int(arrV[index])

    if (i + sub < 0):
      arrV[index] = str(m - (abs(sub) % m))
      sub = int(sub / m)
    else:
      arrV[index] = str(i + sub)
      sub = 0

    index -= 1


  print(arrV)
  return '.'.join(arrV)



print(subtract('1.10.10', 5) == '1.10.5')
print(subtract('1.10.10', 12) == '1.9.8')
print(subtract('1.10.10', 10) == '1.10.0')
print(subtract('1.10.10', 1010) == '1.0.0')
```

Comment: in general case - it is impossible, even your examples contradict to each other

Comment: why `1.1.5` - `6` should be `1.0.9` not `1.0.10`?

Comment: I don’t think you understand how semantic versioning works. For example, after `1.9` comes `1.10`, not `2.0`. Therefore, it’s impossible to tell what came 6 steps before `1.1.5`. Also, as there may be different branches, so there’s even another dimension of ambiguity.

Comment: Apparently base-11 numbers are used here.

Comment: versioning like this isn't a linear progression.  If it was you could just version with one number.    Usually the major/minor/patch can be bumped independently ( except when you bump, you reset every thing to the right) and there's no max number.     But maybe you have some strange ruleset for versioning, but you haven't specified it, other than maybe implying base 11